# Printing float variable with precision set by another variable

Tags: python, rounding, string-formatting, precision

Using python, I would like to print the values of two variables (floats). The precision at which the two variables will be printed, should depend on the variable values themselves. In fact, I will print a value and the associated error. I do not know in advance how many relevant digits "Value" and "Error" will have.

Below some examples:

```
Value: 15236.265, Error = 0.059 --> printed value 15236.27 +- 0.06
Value: 15236.265, Error = 3.738 --> printed value 15236 +- 4
Value: 15236.265, Error = 275.658 --> printed value 15200 +- 300
```

Ideally, I would like to determine the precision to be used in the print statement, as follows.

```
print(Value is {???} and error is {:.1g}).format(value, error)
```

Do you have any suggestion? I am sure the solution is rather simple, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 5):

This is much easier if you use a format string because you can substitute even the formatting parameters in it.  This will let you control all the attributes programmatically:

```
value = 15236.265
error = 3.738
p1    = 10
p2    = 3
print(f"Value is {value:.{p1}g} and error is {error:.{p2}g}")

# 'Value is 15236.265 and error is 3.74'
```

**EDIT**

I see from your comment that this is not a formatting issue but a rounding one.  You want to round the mantissa of the error and apply the same rounding to the value itself.

Here is a function that will do that for you:

```
from math import log
def roundError(N,E):
    p=-round(log(E,10)-0.5)
    return round(N,p),round(E,p)

roundError(15236.265,0.059)   # --> (15236.26, 0.06)
roundError(15236.265,3.738)   # --> (15236, 4)
roundError(15236.265,275.658) # --> (15200, 300)
```

You can then print these numbers without any special formatting.

It may not be a concern for you, but I would like to point out that this value/error adjustment will slightly offset the range of possible values within the error margin.

for example:

```
15236.265 +/- 275.658 ==> 14960.607 ... 15511.923
15200     +/- 300     ==> 14900     ... 15500  (extra 60 low and missing 12 high)
```

To err on the side of caution would probably require the rounded value range to be 14950 ... 15550,  so 15250 +/- 300.  In other words, rounding the value by half the magnitude of the error `round(2*N,p)/2` to account for rounding applied to the value range.

Comment: This does not exactly solve the problem, as I do not know, a priori, how many digits the two values will have. Moreover, p2 should be always 1, and p1 should be a function of the format of error.

Comment: I would say it's still a formatting rather than a rounding one, as I do not need to create any new variable but simply to print them according to specific formatting. Though I agree the difference is subtle. 
In fact, the function you showed, works almost nicelly, except that the function might return values such as (15236.0000001, 4).

Comment: This is due to binary float representation. I changed the function to round the values directly rather than multiplying (but I'm not sure it will cover all cases because some fractions are simply not possible to represent in a binary float).  Which brings the problem back to formatting :).  I suspect you can probably use the value of `p` calculated in the function to figure out a format specification that will work ( p can be negative or positive mind you)

Answer (score 0):

I think we could somehow use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) package to achieve this. I was playing around with it and came up with the following solution. It is quite verbose compared to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56756217/7851470) given by Alain, but probably could be further improved:

```
from decimal import Decimal


def error_format(value: float, 
                 error: float, 
                 significant_digits: int = 1):
    def remove_exponent(d):
        return d.quantize(Decimal(1)) if d == d.to_integral() else d.normalize()

    value = Decimal(str(value))
    error = Decimal(str(error))
    error_exp = error.logb()
    ndigits = -int(error_exp) + significant_digits - 1
    rounded_value = round(value, ndigits)
    rounded_error = round(error, ndigits)
    return remove_exponent(rounded_value), remove_exponent(rounded_error)
```

And the example of usage:

```
values = [15236.265] * 3
errors = [0.059, 3.738, 275.658]

for value, error in zip(values, errors):
    print('Value is {} and error is {}'.format(*error_format(value, error)))

for value, error in zip(values, errors):
    print('Value is {} and error is {}'.format(*error_format(value, error, significant_digits=3)))
```

gives:

```
Value is 15236.26 and error is 0.06
Value is 15236 and error is 4
Value is 15200 and error is 300
Value is 15236.265 and error is 0.059
Value is 15236.26 and error is 3.74
Value is 15236 and error is 276
```